# Making "Play all" in windows explorer work with any media player

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

I uninstalled Windows Media Player from my Windows 7 64-bit install. Now the "Play all" option in explorer does nothing (earlier it used to queue all files in Windows Media Player).

[image: The Play All Button in explorer]

Is there any way to make the play all option use another media player (like VLC)? Setting VLC as the default music player doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on any audio file (eg: .mp3) and click on properties. Under the general tab click the 'Change' button next to 'Opens with:'. Here select a program that you would like to open when using the 'Play All' button (eg: VLC). Accepts these settings by clicking a series of OK's and Apply's. If you have various audio files types (.wav, .wma, etc:), you may need to follow the above steps on these files as well.

But remember, you will need to do this only once per file type.

Comment: I had set VLC to default before, but I did it again once to be sure. Now I find very strange behavior. For example, I have a folder A with 12 mp3 files, and folder B with 5 files. Play All works on B, but not on A.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, as others said, this is a problem related with setting a default player for your media. It works with the Open With menu but there's also another solution. It is more elegant and it allows you to change much fast the default program for a set of extensions. You can find it here:

[How to Associate a File Type or Protocol to a Program](http://www.7tutorials.com/how-associate-file-type-or-protocol-program)